# Storing datatable in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, datatable, viewstate

I was reading this article from Microsoft about the state management.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx

I found an interesting thing here. ViewState is categorized as Client Side option (Although I already knew that). It reminds me of our code in the application.

```
DataTable dt = getDatatableFromDB();
ViewState["dataTable"] = dt;
```

And this code is working fine at the moment.

My confusion is :

1. How can a client side object(ViewState) save Server side object(Datatable)?
2. Is it a good practice to use ViewState for storing large objects like Datatables?
3. What possibly could be the side effect(if any) if we keep on using this approach?

Comment: Downvoters - if you do not leave comments, the OP will never learn how to ask better questions. Personally, I see no problem with this question. I believe it is useful to the community, so I'm adding a +1 to balance things out.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 World is a better place to live because of people like you. I am fairly new to this technology and I am trying to learn and remove my confusions. That's why I am asking questions like these. But some Downvoters think what is known to them is known to everyone and no one should ask those question. It reminds me a Chinese proverb "He who ask a question is a fool for five minutes he who does not ask a question remains a fool forever.". Lolz

Comment: Thanks, but there is actually a standard by which to judge good/bad questions - meaning not all questions on StackOverflow are welcome (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). I just don't see an issue with yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The viewstate is stored in a hidden `<input />` tag on the form. When the user initiates a postback (by clicking a button, for example), the data is returned to the server as part of the form data.

If you store large amounts of data in the ViewState, you will incur a penalty both when the user attempts to download the page (because all that data will be part of the HTML) and when the user attempts to submit the form (because all that data must be uploaded back to the server).

In addition, the ViewState is easily lost. It is only preserved as long as the user is submitting the form. If the user clicks a hyperlink to another page, the form is never submitted and all the data contained within the ViewState is lost. This is true even if the anchor tag points back to the page the user is currently on.

I see from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811932/using-session-to-store-datatable) that you are trying to find a good place to put your DataTables. ViewState is not the worst place as long as the data is relatively small. Base64 is better than XML in terms of memory usage but it is still a long way from efficient. If the data is fairly static, you may want to consider storing it in the [ApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you are editing the DataTable with a GridView, then the GridView is actually already storing the DataTable for you which you can access via the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) property (just cast it back to a DataTable).

---

It is also worth noting that while the ViewState data is encoded in base64 (meaning the average user will not be able to understand it), it can be easily edited by a determined user. Seemingly innocuous data could be edited to become quite harmful to your website. This is a classic avenue for hacking a website, so you must be very careful about what data, exactly, you are storing. For example, if you store the user's ID in the ViewState, the user could edit the ID and hack into another user's account. (*Note: this is only an issue if EnableViewStateMac has been set to `False`.*)

Comment: Side note: It is serialized into the input value and deserialized on its way back.

Comment: @Cyborgx37, Will enableViewStateMAC help in the case of editing ViewState?

Comment: Yes, `EnableViewStateMac` will go a long way toward preventing ViewState hacking.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Yes I have read about the Application. But Application will be shared plus it is using server's memory. And we don't have control over the Application memory management like we have with Cache. So if I am going to select between Application and Cache, my vote is for Cache.

Comment: I should have elaborated on "static" - I meant to also include that the data is the same for all users (for example, a lookup table). In that case, the memory footprint would be negligible. But it all depends on your project, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

1)  How can a client side object(ViewState) save Server side object(Datatable)?

It is serialized.

2)  Is it a good practice to use ViewState for storing large objects like Datatables?

It depends on your environment and requirements.

3)  What possibly could be the side effect(if any) if we keep on using this approach?

A lot of data will be going over the wire.  It could slow things down.

Comment: Another side note: Serializing a large object will also cause it to slow down.. not just the wire transfer.